# Error in Import App pools from windows server 2016 to windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool, iis-10

I am trying to export using appcmd from a windows server 2016 (IIS 10) to a windows server 2012 R2(IIS 8.5). I am getting an error hresult:8007000B command execution failed data is invalid. Due to some reasons I can not use webDeploy tool here. Any suggestion please

Comment: Why would you go from 2016 to 2012? Are you sure AppPools are backwards compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below to solve this question:

1. Run appcmd as administrator.
2. Try to enable 32-bit application in application pool advanced setting.
3. Ensure you have synced the config file.